# error in runing source face detection in opencv 2.4.9 and vs 2012

Tags: opencv, c++11, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

i use pre-build opencv 2.4.9 i test the image show in opencv 2.4.9 it works,but for this source its have error?! if this errors is that i use pre-build opencv?what to do what not to do
i copy the xml file in current folder and my hardware corei5,Radeon ATI graphic

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/ml.h>

void doMosaic(IplImage* in, int x, int y,
              int width, int height, int size);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
    {
    int i, c;
    IplImage *src_img = 0, *src_gray = 0;
    const char *cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
    CvHaarClassifierCascade *cascade = 0;
    CvMemStorage *storage = 0;
    CvSeq *faces;

    cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade *) cvLoad (cascade_name, 0, 0, 0);
    cvNamedWindow ("Capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    CvCapture *capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    assert(capture != NULL);

    while (1) {
        src_img = cvQueryFrame (capture);
        src_gray = cvCreateImage (cvGetSize(src_img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

        storage = cvCreateMemStorage (0);
        cvClearMemStorage (storage);
        cvCvtColor (src_img, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvEqualizeHist (src_gray, src_gray);

        faces = cvHaarDetectObjects (src_gray, cascade, storage,
            1.11, 4, 0, cvSize (40, 40));
        for (i = 0; i < (faces ? faces->total : 0); i++) {
            CvRect *r = (CvRect *) cvGetSeqElem (faces, i);
            doMosaic(src_img, r->x, r->y, r->width, r->height, 20);
            }

        cvShowImage("Capture", src_img);
        cvReleaseImage(&src_gray);

        c = cvWaitKey (2);
        if (c == '\x1b')
            break;
        }

    cvReleaseCapture (&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow ("Capture");

    return 0;
    }

void doMosaic(IplImage* in, int x0, int y0,
              int width, int height, int size)
    {
    int b, g, r, col, row;

    int xMin = size*(int)floor((double)x0/size);
    int yMin = size*(int)floor((double)y0/size);
    int xMax = size*(int)ceil((double)(x0+width)/size);
    int yMax = size*(int)ceil((double)(y0+height)/size);

    for(int y=yMin; y<yMax; y+=size){
        for(int x=xMin; x<xMax; x+=size){
            b = g = r = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
                if( y+i > in->height ){
                    break;
                    }
                row = i;
                for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
                    if( x+j > in->width ){
                        break;
                        }
                    b += (unsigned char)in->imageData[in->widthStep*(y+i)+(x+j)*3];
                    g += (unsigned char)in->imageData[in->widthStep*(y+i)+(x+j)*3+1];
                    r += (unsigned char)in->imageData[in->widthStep*(y+i)+(x+j)*3+2];
                    col = j;
                    }
                }
            row++;
            col++;
            for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                    in->imageData[in->widthStep*(y+i)+(x+j)*3]   = cvRound((double)b/(row*col));
                    in->imageData[in->widthStep*(y+i)+(x+j)*3+1] = cvRound((double)g/(row*col));
                    in->imageData[in->widthStep*(y+i)+(x+j)*3+2] = cvRound((double)r/(row*col));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the error is a break in microsoft ,please help me.thanks very much

```
First-chance exception at 0x75C4B727 in opencv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x003CF678.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i succeed,i first for PDB errors tools>option>debugging>outputwindow>moduleloadmessage >off and then i tools>option>debugging>symbols>microsoft symbols server not checked and then i chnge capture.open( -1 ); to capture.open( 0 ); now by seting in opencv itworks,thanks very much